# Date Format match between client and server

Tags: ajax, asp.net-mvc, datetime, asp.net-web-api

Am posting an object from client to server via AJAX in ASP Net which consist of date Property too.MY Machine's time zone uses the date format **MM/dd/yyyy** in string whereas my server time zone uses the format **dd/MM/yyyy**.Am still wondering that how do the conversion takes place properly and it works as expected result which gets saved in the database.

Say for example am posting a value from client 02/01/2016(MM/dd/yyyy) in string which gets changed properly in server to 01/02/2016(dd/MM/yyyy). How do they know that the incoming value was in (MM/dd/yyyy) and then parses to (dd/MM/yyyy).

Let me know if i was wrong/misunderstood.

Comment: you can't understand it without additional info. You either should post date in right format from your client either post locale with your date to understand how to parce it on server side.

Comment: Will there will be any culture related info will be passed along with the request in ASP Net. If so it would be helpful if you could share those info.

Comment: It depends on your situation, and i don't see code.